# Xamarin iOS using HttpWebRequest vs HttpClient on iOS device

Tags: xamarin.ios, httpwebrequest, httpclient

I have a Xamarin iOS app which uses HttpClient to make Get/Post web requests. Most of the times HttpClient throws "A task was canceled" error. I think it because of timeout getting response back. However, if i use HttpWebRequest it works fine. 
Are there any limitations using HttpClient in iOS apps.
Here is the code

```
        try
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + tokenVal);
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, requestUri);

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                returnStr = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            returnStr = "Error:" + ex.Message;
        }
```

Comment: Chances are you are not making the request properly with HttpClient and may be experiencing a deadlock which is cause the client to time out. Without a [mcve] of your code this would be only a guess.

Comment: I have added my code above

Comment: You will need to provide more than that. That code is encapsulated in what kind of method. How is it being called? These are all things needed to help identify possible causes of your problem.